# How to programmatically turn on/off WiFi in iOS? [Swift]

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

NOTE: I am aware that such a thing violates user's privacy and would be rejected by Apple. However, this specific component is purely for automated testing of buffering behavior when the user's connection is poor/nonexistent. It will NOT be publicly released.

With that said, does anyone know of a way to programmatically turn on/off WiFi in iOS?

I have not been able to find anything up-to-date. Pretty much every answer has to do with this being a violation of privacy and cautioning that they shouldn't do it. Doesn't apply in my case.

Closest I could find was using something like DeviceFarm to simulate it https://docs.aws.amazon.com/devicefarm/latest/developerguide/how-to-simulate-network-connections-and-conditions.html

However, in my case I want these tests to run entirely within the app (private test build). Setting up DeviceFarm for this purpose alone isn't worth it imo.

Comment: You can use Network Link Conditioner on both macOS and iOS but I don't believe there is any way to automate changing its settings

Answer (score 1):

There is no provision provided by apple to change automate changing its settings because of apple's privacy rule. So you can't achieve by any way.

Answer (score 0):

You can’t. Apple does not allow 3rd party apps to change global system settings like that.
There is no API available to control cellular data,wi-fi,bluetooth within in an app , User have to go to settings to enable or disable cellular data,wi-fi and bluetooth.
This is not possible in iOS unless you jailbroke your device. Apple is not allowing any apps developer to access wifi/bluetooth. You can only check wifi/tooth is connected or not.
You can’t do that using the iOS application. Apple not allowing it.
Legally there is no way to do it. Even somehow if you are manage to do it, Apple will reject your app while submitting to AppStore.